# How to delete drawn text in createJS

Tags: text, createjs

I have this function

```
var textHowTo;
this.drawString = function(textToDraw, props, color, posX, posY, containerbox, lineW, aligns)
    {
        console.log("Draw String");
        var textContent_1 = textToDraw;
        textHowTo = new createjs.Text(textContent_1, props, color);

        var w = ( textHowTo.getMeasuredWidth() ) * textHowTo.scaleX;
        var h = ( textHowTo.getMeasuredHeight() ) * textHowTo.scaleY;

        //textHowTo.regY = h / 2;
        textHowTo.textAlign = aligns; 
        if (lineW > 0)
            textHowTo.lineWidth = lineW;

        //textHowTo.font = 'assets/fonts/Elite Hacker (Corroded).ttf';
        textHowTo.x = posX;
        textHowTo.y = posY;
        containerbox.addChild(textHowTo);
    }
```

**textHowTo** is my global text Instance

and on the init page I called it like this :

```
this.GS_Gameplay_Init = function ()
{
    module.drawString( TEXT.EN.GP_TEXT_TUTORIAL_1 , "30px Hacker", "#ffffff", (FAR_ANCHOR<<1)+50, (FAR_ANCHOR<<1) + 100, finish_containerbox, 300, 'center');

    module.drawString( TEXT.EN.GP_TEXT_TUTORIAL_2 , "15px Hacker", "#ffffff", (FAR_ANCHOR<<1)+50, (FAR_ANCHOR<<1) + 250, finish_containerbox, 200, 'center');
}
```

My question how do I remove both of them?
I have tried using this :

```
finish_containerbox.removeChild(textHowTo);
```

But only the last text(TEXT.EN.GP_TEXT_TUTORIAL_2 ) removed.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on @Barman's answer, you need to save references to your instances so you can remove them later.

If you're dealing with an indeterminate number of instances, then you'll probably want to use an array.

`var textInstances = [];
// ...
textInstances.push(this.drawString(...)); // drawString should return the instance
// ...
while (textInstances.length) {
   var text = textInstances.pop();
   text.parent.removeChild(text);
}`

Answer (score 1):

You could use 
    finish_containerbox.removeAllChildren();

or have your function 'drawString' return the instance 
    this.myText1 = this.drawString(..);
    this.finish_containerbox.addChild(this.myText1);
    this.myText2 = this.drawString(..);
    this.finish_containerbox.addChild(this.myText2);

and later use these vars to remove the instance:
    this.finish_containerbox.removeChild(this.myText1);
    this.finish_containerbox.removeChild(this.myText2);

Comment: No, I cant remove all children. Because it will remove all object. And also cant do it with  mmyText1/2, what if I have 100 text?

Comment: You can't use a global instance if you are making more than one, since each time you make it, it will overwrite the reference to the earlier one.